# How to get text inside div tag in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I recently made a program to notify me if the game server is offline or online but I think there's a much simple version of my program. Btw. The website associated in this project is

http://stats.teamextrememc.com/iframe_status.php

It returns n of 150 players, (Online)wait, and Offline displayed in the page and in the title.
I know how to get the title of a web document by using `document.Title` but I only need the 
number of players(n) not the "of 150 players" and I also want to play sound file if the server is online or offline(If the server is online, the page returns "n of 150 players" but the (Online)wait is considered offline)

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private stat As String
Private time As Integer
Private DocTitle As String
Private Onetime As Boolean = False
Public Sub PlaySoundFile(ByVal SoundPath As String)
    PlaySound.SoundLocation = SoundPath
    PlaySound.Load()
    PlaySound.Play()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    refresher.Start()

End Sub
Private PlaySound As New System.Media.SoundPlayer
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles refresher.Tick
    DocTitle = browser.DocumentTitle
    time += 1
    Label1.Text = DocTitle
    If time = 5 Then
        browser.Refresh()
        time = 0
    End If

    If DocTitle = "Offline" And Onetime = False Then
        PlaySoundFile("C:/down.wav")
        Onetime = True
    ElseIf DocTitle <> "Offline" And Onetime = True Then
        PlaySoundFile("C:/up.wav")
        Onetime = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
End Sub
End Class
```

And this is what the page returns when open it in a browser:

```
<!doctype html><html>
<head>
<title>150 of 150 players</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="20">
<style>
body {
margin:0; padding:0;
background-color:transparent;
color:#66FF00;
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
     }
#statuserr {color:#FF3636}
.white { color: #EEE; font-size:11px }
.dark { background-color:#333; font-size:24px }
</style>
</head>
<body class="">
<div class="">150 of 150 players<br/></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML will always be that simple, you should be able to just call `document.body.innerText' or 'document.documentElement.textContent', depending on what engine your 'browser' object uses.

If that site is yours, you may want to adjust the PHP to return JSON or XML instead of HTML.  (XML has the bonus of letting you specify a stylesheet, so the same URL can work in both a browser and as a program query.)